# OneJar "Enter Java Package Name"

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, onejar

I'm trying to build my project, with contains multiple other JARS and natives, into one fat jar. I was pointed into using the onejar project, which can be found here: http://one-jar.sourceforge.net

When running one jar with the command line, I am prompted with

```
Enter project path (project name is last segment): c:/tmp/test-one-jar
Enter java package name: com.example.onejar
```

I put in my prioject directory for the first question, but I am confused what the second prompt is asking for. What does it mean by java package name? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle at all?

Comment: I'm not using build automation.

Comment: It means the java package your code is in. See the folders in the file system where you have placed your code. Also look at the "package" declaration at the top of your java file.

Comment: So would just putting "src" be acceptable?